# LogonUser is slow to return with bad credentials on Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows

I use LogonUser to verify credentials. On Windows 7 PCs, if it fails, the user might have to wait 30 seconds for the function to return. This does not happen on XP - the function returns very quickly. Here is my code:

```
HANDLE hToken;

bool bSuccess = LogonUser(StringUserName, "MyDomain", StringPassword, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, &hToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea how Windows' particular API handles this, but it is generally considered a good idea not to return immediately when logon credentials are bad, to avoid brute force attacks. I could imagine Windows added this feature since WinXP.

Comment: It also may take the Domain Controller a while to determine the credential is bad.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: 30 seconds? I expect some serious SQL querying to run faster than that, let alone a comparatively simple credential lookup.